# $(window).height() not working on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I'm trying to learn about window height and viewport. I made the following:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   for(var count=0; count < 100; count++) 
      $("body").append("<div><button class=\"hhh\">HELLO</button></div>");

});

$(document).on("click",".hhh",function(event) {
   console.log($(window).height());
   console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});

$(window).resize(function() {
       console.log($(window).height());  
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I resize the window and click the button the $(window).height() always remains the same. I would have expected this value to change... Can anyone please tell me why it's remaining constant. I'm using the latest version of Chrome on a mac.

Comment: are you perhaps looking for $(document).height()? Also, the best place to check the size if at the resize event.

Comment: does it work if you try console.log($(window).height()); in a js console ?

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 using $(document).height() gives the same results...

Comment: You are definitely having some other issue, if you try this example on the same browser and it works look carefully at the differences. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dim_width_height2

Comment: What were you expecting the height to be? Window height including scrollable regions? I don't think jquery's height function includes those.

Comment: I thought that resizing the browser window would have reduced the $(window).height() return value

Comment: Works fine for me in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sw2kruvq/

Comment: What happens when you just use window.innerHeight instead of the jQuery function?

Comment: From the screenshot you just posted the height of that window IS zero. (you removed the entire document area with the developer tools.)

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 No I didn't click the button that time. I added the resize event and simply started resizing the window. That's why the value is repeated so many times. It's me moving and resizing the window...

Comment: @Robba using window.innerHeight seems to works correctly for the resize...Still don't understand why the jquery $(window).height() isn't working though...

Comment: @MarMan29 to simplify this just remove window.resize and console.log(scrollTop). Now click on your button and see the output. Resize the window and click again. Are they still the same ? I tested it and it works fine for me. https://jsbin.com/nutacu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Ok everyone I found this article that i think might explain it http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-window-height-incorrect/

Comment: @Robba your solution of using innerHeight worked regardless...

Comment: Happy to see that you at least found a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a shot to this code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
       console.log($(window).height());  
});
```

that works for me but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

> EDIT:

Could you please close the developer tools and include an alert in your code? You are getting back a different context for your height (you are getting the height for the debugger console not for the window). Try it and let us know if it doesn't work.

> EDIT 2:

Just tried your exact same code compared to one of my test and the only difference I can see is that I have this at the top of my HTML document:

When I remove that from the document on Chrome I get the full height of the window (not zero) if I add it back I get the different sizes based on the resizing I do. What specific browser are you using? could it be that you are using an old browser?

Comment: Nope it stays the same for me. value printed to console is always the same 1816

Comment: I tried the above code and chrome and firefox both with the console window open and the height() doesn't change so I think there's something wrong with the code...

Answer (score 1):

Ok this article explains things. I've never included a < !DOCTYPE HTML> on my html I guess this was a mistake...

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-window-height-incorrect/